# using sed in script to add html tag to text

Tags: html, bash, tags, sed

I'm trying to use sed in a shell script to add html hyperlink tags to a url in a plain text file.

This is the content of my newtext.txt:

```
www.example.com
```

And here is the desired content of newtext.txt that I would like after running my script:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
```

Here is the content of my current script, addhtml.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
newtextv='cat newtext.txt'
sed -i.bak 's|\(www.*\)|<a href="$newtextv">\1</a>|' newtext.txt
```

But unfortunately, after running the script, the content of newtext.txt becomes:

```
<a href="$newtextv">www.example.com</a>
```

I believe my error somehow relates to how my variable is being quoted?

I eventually want this script to also be able to convert full urls (containing http:// )... I obviously need to improve my sed knowledge a good deal (it's taken me a few days to get this far), but I can't wrap my head around this one.

Thank you!

Comment: I appreciate all the help! I promise to give support back to the community when I have the skills to. Thank you! I wish I was able to vote up all of you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the file's content into a variable:

```
newtextv=$(cat newtext.txt)
```

But really, you probably want something like this (but with a better regex, obviously):

```
sed 's|www\.[^ ]*|<a href="&">&</a>|g' <newtext.txt >newtext.html
```

Sed replaces every `&` with the matched string.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me a ton for my question, and also a few other things I'm trying to do at the moment. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Why mess around with a variable?

```
sed -i 's|\(www.*\)|<a href="\1">\1</a>|' newtext.txt
```

or

```
sed -i 's|www.*|<a href="&">&</a>|' newtext.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have the URL in a variable you can also do it without sed:

```
newtextv=www.example.com
echo "<a href=\"http://${newtextv#www.}\">$newtextv</a>"
```

returns

```
<a href="http://example.com">www.example.com</a>
```

In Bash you can [manipulate variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) as a subset of variable substitution.
Here `${newtextv#www.}` basically means take `$newtextv` and cut "www." from its beginning

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help and the extra info. I think perhaps this might be the better route for what I am trying to accomplish, as it will work with a full url also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is two little syntax errors:

1. `cat newtext.txt` will never execute, you need to use backquotes `` ` `` or `$()`
2. using single quotes `'` prevents variables from expanding. To allow variable expansion use double quotes `"`

here is what you want to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
newtextv=$(cat newtext.txt)
sed -i.bak "s|\(www.*\)|<a href=\"$newtextv\">\1</a>|" newtext.txt
```